# Apache Lucene fuzzy search for multi-worded phrases

Tags: lucene, fuzzy-search

I have the following Apache Lucene 7 application:

```
StandardAnalyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(standardAnalyzer);
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
Document document = new Document();

document.add(new TextField("content", new FileReader("document.txt"))); 
writer.addDocument(document);
writer.close();

IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

Query fuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "Company"), 2);

TopDocs results = searcher.search(fuzzyQuery, 5);
System.out.println("Hits: " + results.totalHits);
System.out.println("Max score:" + results.getMaxScore())
```

when I use it with :

```
new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "Company"), 2);
```

the application works fine and returns the following result:

```
Hits: 1
Max score:0.35161147
```

but when I try to search with multi term query, for example:

new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "Company name"), 2);

it returns the following result:

```
Hits: 0
Max score:NaN
```

Anyway, the phrase `Company name` exists in the source `document.txt` file.

How to properly use `FuzzyQuery` in this case in order to be able to do the fuzzy search for multi-word phrases.

**UPDATED**

Based on the provided solution I have tested it on the following text information:

```
Company name: BlueCross BlueShield              Customer Service 
   1-800-521-2227           
                        of Texas                          Preauth-Medical              1-800-441-9188           
                                                          Preauth-MH/CD                1-800-528-7264           
                                                          Blue Card Access             1-800-810-2583
```

For the following query:

```
SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[2];
clauses[0] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "BlueCross"), 2));
clauses[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "BlueShield"), 2));
SpanNearQuery query = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 0, true);
```

the search works fine:

```
Hits: 1
Max score:0.5753642
```

but when I try to corrupt a little bit the search query(for example from `BlueCross` to `BlueCros`)

```
SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[2];
clauses[0] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "BlueCros"), 2));
clauses[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "BlueShield"), 2));
SpanNearQuery query = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 0, true);
```

it stops working and returns:

```
Hits: 0
Max score:NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the following, you're using `TextField`, which is tokenizing field. E.g. your text `"Company name is working on something"` would be effectively split by spaces (and others delimeters). So, even if you have the text `Company name`, during indexation it will become `Company`, `name`, `is`, etc.

In this case this TermQuery won't be able to find what you're looking for. The trick which going to help you would look like this:

```
SpanQuery[] clauses = new SpanQuery[2];
    clauses[0] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "some"), 2));
    clauses[1] = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new FuzzyQuery(new Term("content", "text"), 2));
    SpanNearQuery query = new SpanNearQuery(clauses, 0, true);
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach much, especially if your load would be big and you're planning on searching on a 10 term long company names. One should be aware, that those query are potentially heavy to execute.

The following problem with `BlueCros` is the following. By default Lucene uses **StandardAnalyzer** for TextField. So it means it effectively lowercase the terms, basically it means that `BlueCross` in the `content` field becomes `bluecross`.

Fuzzy difference between `BlueCros` and `bluecross` is 3, that's the reason you do not have a match.

Simple proposal would be to convert term in query to the lowercase, by doing something like `.toLowerCase()`

In general, one should prefer to use same analyzers during the query time as well (e.g. during construction of the query)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with the current results. Could you please check what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: @alexanoid updated, however, i would recommend to prevent further edits since this question become too broad and all-around

Answer (score 0):

For Lucene.Net it can be like this.

```
private string _IndexPath = @"Your Index Path";
private Directory _Directory;
private Searcher _IndexSearcher;
private MultiPhraseQuery _MultiPhraseQuery;

_Directory = FSDirectory.Open(_IndexPath);
IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.Open(_Directory, true);

string field = "Name" // Your field name
string keyword = "big red fox"; // your search term 
float fuzzy = 0,7f; // between 0-1
using (_IndexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader))
{
    // "big red fox" to [big,red,fox]
    var keywordSplit = keyword.Split();

    _MultiPhraseQuery = new MultiPhraseQuery();
    FuzzyTermEnum[] _FuzzyTermEnum = new FuzzyTermEnum[keywordSplit.Length];
    Term[] _Term = new Term[keywordSplit.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < keywordSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        _FuzzyTermEnum[i] = new FuzzyTermEnum(indexReader, new Term(field, keywordSplit[i]),fuzzy);
        _Term[i] = _FuzzyTermEnum[i].Term;
        if (_Term[i] == null)
        {
            _MultiPhraseQuery.Add(new Term(field, keywordSplit[i]));
        }
        else
        {
            _MultiPhraseQuery.Add(_FuzzyTermEnum[i].Term);
        }
    }

    var results = _IndexSearcher.Search(_MultiPhraseQuery, indexReader.MaxDoc);

    foreach (var loopDoc in results.ScoreDocs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Score))
    {
        //YourCode Here
    }
}
```